# Laravel get user today and tomorrow birthday

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query to get tomorrow and today birthday users:

```
$birthday[Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')] = User::whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%m-%d')")
        ->orWhereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(birthday,'%m-%d') = '02-29' and DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m') = '02' AND 
        LAST_DAY(NOW()) = DATE(NOW())")
        ->selectRaw('first_name, last_name, email, birthday')
        ->get();

$birthday[Carbon::now()->addDay()->format('Y-m-d')] = User::whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '%m-%d')")
        ->orWhereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(birthday,'%m-%d') = '02-29' and DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m') = '02' AND 
            LAST_DAY(NOW()) = DATE(NOW())")
        ->selectRaw('first_name, last_name, email, birthday')
        ->get();

 return $birthday;
```

The query will give me this result:

```
{
    "2016-03-30": [
        {
          "first_name": "Harmon",
          "last_name": "Olson",
          "email": "GleasonSwaniawski.Jeanne@yahoo.com",
          "birthday": "1990-03-30"
        },
        {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Doe",
          "email": "john.doe@yahoo.com",
          "birthday": "1990-03-30"
        },
    ],
    "2016-03-31": [
        {
          "first_name": "User10",
          "last_name": null,
          "email": "user10@user.com",
          "birthday": "1990-03-31"
        }
    ]
}
```

Sure it worked properly and the result exactly what I wanted, But I think my query can be shorten (combine the query become one) to get what I want achieve.

Any advice how to shorten it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want result as above or in a single array will do for you?

Answer (score 10):

For getting today's birthday use

```php
User::whereMonth('birth_date', Carbon::now()->format('m'))
->whereDay('birth_date', Carbon::now()->format('d'))
->get();
```

And for tomorrow birthday's

```php
User::whereMonth('birth_date', Carbon::now()->format('m'))
->whereDay('birth_date', Carbon::now()->addDay()->format('d'))
->get();
```

Note:- `birth_date` column date format is `yyyy-mm-dd` and data type is `date` in table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\App\User::whereRaw("STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', MONTH(dob), '-', DAY(dob), '%Y-%m-%d' ) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)")->get();
```

Or for tomorrow:

```
\App\User::whereRaw("STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', MONTH(dob), '-', DAY(dob), '%Y-%m-%d' ) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)")->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid RAW queries:

```
$birtday['today'] = User::whereDate('birthday', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());

$birtday['tomorrow'] = User::whereDate('birthday', '=', Carbon::tomorrow()->toDateString());
```

Comment: It will - Carbon handles those pretty well.

Comment: I've tried your query but it return me null. I think because your query will check the birthday by exact date. example birthday is '1990-03-31' and it will check with '2016-03-31'

Comment: This query will check if there is a birthday with the exact date of today.